# Как сделать цикл какой то математической задачи

Tags: c#

```
float x, y, stepen, znam, zna;
Console.Write("Введите данные x=");
x = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Введите данные y=");
y = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
stepen = 1;
znam = 1;
zna = 2;



while (stepen< 10)
{
    stepen++;
    zna++;
    znam = znam * zna;

    double Z = 1 - Math.Pow(x, stepen) / znam + Math.Pow(y, stepen) / znam - Math.Pow(x, stepen) / znam + Math.Pow(y, stepen) / znam;
    Console.WriteLine(Z);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

`Math.Pow(x, stepen) / znam + Math.Pow(y, stepen) / znam - Math.Pow(x, stepen) / znam + Math.Pow(y, stepen) / znam` - чтобы вот эта часть продолжалось пока степень меньше 10, я только начал изучать этот язык, поэтому прошу прощения за возможно очевидные ошибки. а сама фукнция выглядит как на картинке. вариант 6

[image: постановка задачи]

Comment: А сейчас что не так?

Comment: @Эникейщик она остановится на том месте где я перестал писать математическую задачу, а мне нужно чтобы он повторялся сам по себе, пока степень меньше 10.

Comment: @Akina, прошу прощения если не ясно выразился

Comment: Как я понял, мой ответ вам не зашел, потому что вы хотите только готовое решение, а не понять, как это в принципе можно решить, верно?

Comment: @aepot, я читал ваш ответ и пытался сам написать из того что вы мне разжевали, могу показать свою крокозябру что я пытался написать))) поэтому пошел на ютубчик и в гугл как вы и посоветовали, извините что не ответил на ваш ответ просто, мой код очень не совпадал с тем что писал другой человек и у меня был дисонанс чего я написал, ощущается своя ущербность в этом деле честно говоря эхх(((

Comment: @azik.krazy ничего страшного, все мы когда-то учились писать код. Моя цель была именно объяснить, а не решить, поэтому я взял другой вариант. Если вам что-то еще из моего решения непонятно, напишите комментарий под ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте объясню первую формулу.

1. Начнем с того, что переменные лучше объявлять там, где происходит их первое использование, если возможно. Так код легче читать. А то представьте, что вы объявили все что нужно в первой строчке кода, а потом прокрутили 2 экрана вниз. И попробуй разберись, что там какого типа. Разобраться конечно можно, но это будет значительно легче сделать, если последовать моему совету.
2. Второе, есть цикл `for`, и есть условие `if`. Как они работают, я не буду объяснять, как минимум потому что это очень легко гуглится в огромных количествах. Привыкайте использовать цикл `for` там, где заранее известно, с чего начинаем, чем заканчиваем, и как изменяется счетчик. `while` больше подходит для проверки состояния чего то типа `while (IsAlive) { ... }`, то есть проверка логической переменной без счетчика, или вообще бесконечный цикл `while (true)`. А когда нужен счетчик - там `for`.
3. Чтобы узнать четное число или нечетное, можно просто найти остаток от деления на 2, работает это обычно только с целыми числами, ну потому что вещественные числа всегда делятся точно, а не на цело. Вычисляется так `int b = a % 2`, то есть если остаток от деления `1`, число нечетное, ну а что иначе - сами догадайтесь. Следовательно вот такого условия нам будет достаточно `if (i % 2 == 0) { ... }`, чтобы получить последовательность `+-+-+-`.
4. Просто для справки: запись `i = i + 2` можно кратко записать как `i += 2`, то же самое с минусом, умножением и делением, я просто буду писать именно так, не удивляйтесь.
5. Дело вкуса, но вместо `Convert.To...(...)` я использую `<тип>.Parse(...)`, ну потому что мне так удобнее. Смысл `Convert` в том, что он умеет переваривать не только строки, но и объекты другого типа (зависит от типа, в который происходит конвертация), а `.Parse` - только строки.
6. Форматирвоание вывода. `double` и `float` поддерживают особые правила форматирования, о которых можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings). Попробуйте сами разобраться, что значит `F3` в коде ниже.

Для разнообразия, я взял первую формулу из вашей таблицы - **Вариант 1**.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите x = ");
    double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Введите y = ");
    double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Введите n = ");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    double j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        double k = i * 2 - 1; //1..3..5...7
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            j += Math.Pow(Math.Sin(Math.Pow(x, i)), k + 2) / (k * (k + 2));
        }
        else
        {
            j -= Math.Pow(Math.Sin(Math.Pow(y, i)), k + 2) / (k * (k + 2));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"j = {j:F3}");
}
```

Ну и все остальные формулы у вас аналогичные, не сложнее, не легче.

*P.S. По-английски "степень" будет "power" (поэтому кстати `Math.Pow()`), старайтесь избегать транслита в именах переменных, его сложно читать, лучше гуглите как что-то переводится на английский, заодно и слова подучите*

Answer (score 0):

Вроде так. Для вычисления факториала понадобится дополнительная функция
**Вариант 6**

```
    static int GetFactorial(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return n * GetFactorial(n - 1);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите X: ");
        double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите Y: ");
        double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите длину ряда: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double z = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 1)
                z += (Math.Pow(y, i-1)) / GetFactorial(i);
            else
                z -= (Math.Pow(x, i-1)) / GetFactorial(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Z = {z}");
    }
```

P.S. Вариант 2 (пусть будет) :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите X: ");
            double x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите Y: ");
            double y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите длину ряда: ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double Z = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    Z += (Math.Pow(y, i) / ((i + 1) * (i + 3) * (i + 5)));
                else
                    Z += -1*(Math.Pow(x, i) / ((i + 1) * (i + 3) * (i + 5)));
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Z = {Z}");
        }
```

Comment: кстати, вы увидели то что я пропустил))) вот это я глупый, забыл что количество слагаемых вводит пользователь.

Comment: В цикл нужно было впихнуть расчет элемента ряда, в зависимости от индекса. И , получается, выполнять цикл столько раз, какая длина будет указана )

Comment: `Z += -1*` = `Z -=` :)

Comment: Тоже верно xD Видите, каждый тупит по своему)

Comment: @KennY3 а если не сложно можете объяснить как вы написали формулу для знаменателя и куда подевалась 1- ? просто сравнил результаты кода и калькулятор, и они отличаются.

Comment: Честно, вполне возможно, что результат будет неверный, потому что программу я толком не проверял xD. А знаменатель, смотрите, его берем из индекса. Множители будут такие: Первый = индекс +1, второй = индекс +3, третий = индекс +5. И так далее и считаем по этой закономерности

Comment: Вы же решали 2ую задачу?

Comment: @azik.krazy А про какой 1- вы говорите? Я в условии не вижу ничего...

Comment: @KennY нет я 6 брал)))

Comment: @azik.krazy А, а я решал 2ую)

Comment: @azik.krazy Добавил вариант 6

Comment: ааа, спасибо большое, видели бы вы щас что я пытался сам написать)))

Comment: @KennY3 не знаю насколько это правильно, но я поменял первый факториал на 2, то есть i=2 изначально, и при выводе  z  сложил туда единичку. и вроде результат правильный выводит, это если кому на будущее понадобится.